# Trying to connect to Oracle with LINQPad give "Can not obtain Oracle client information"

Tags: oracle, linqpad

I'm trying to connect either LINQPad 4 or LINQPad 5 to an Oracle database on a new Windows 2016 server using the OCI connection. I can open up SQl Developer and it connects but when I try with LINQPad I get "Can not obtain Oracle client information from registry. Make sure that Oracle Client Software is installed, or use Direct mode of connecting to the server". If I try using Direct Mode and supply it with the server name I get "Connection was refused with error ORA-12504".

I just put our first console app on the server that connects to that Oracle database and it was able to connect and return data.

On our Windows 2008 servers that have been up and running for a while, I have been able to connect to Oracle with LINQPad for the last 3+ years. The only thing I can think of a difference is that on the 2008 servers it was 32bit Oracle and now we are using 64 bit.

I'm looking for any suggestions on what I can try. I would prefer to use LINQPad instead of SQL Developer if possible.

Answer (score 0):

After more research I found the following post and it worked for me. Posting in case someone else can use this. I'm using tnsname.ora file as well.

[LINQPad - Connection String to my Oracle DB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19404899/linqpad-connection-string-to-my-oracle-db/28944210#28944210)